# synchronizing find with rsync on remote server

Tags: shell

I'm trying to sync (version 3.1.2), files newer than 5 days from a remote server to a drive mapped on my machine (another server).
The rsync command is working without find:

```
sshpass -p "password" rsync -rltgoDv admin@10.98.9.34:/results/analysis/output/Home/*/plugin_out/coverageAnalysis_out.*/*.xls /home/balasat/mdl3/Test
```

and find is working without rsycn command as well:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh admin@10.98.9.34 find /results/analysis/output/Home/*/plugin_out/coverageAnalysis_out.*/*.xls -type f -mtime -5
```

However, when the two are combined rsync is not finding the files. I have tried several ways:

```
shpass -p "password" ssh admin@10.98.9.34 find /results/analysis/output/Home/*/plugin_out/coverageAnalysis_out.*/*.xls -type f -mtime -5 -exec rsync {} /home/balasat/mdl3/Test \;
```

error: find: missing argument to -exec

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh admin@10.98.9.34 find /results/analysis/output/Home/*/plugin_out/coverageAnalysis_out.*/*.xls -type f -mtime -5 > admin@10.98.9.34:/tmp/rsyncfiles
sshpass -p "password" rsync -rltgoDv --files-from=/tmp/rsyncfiles admin@10.98.9.34: /home/balasat/mdl3/Test
```

error: No such file or directory,
even though the correct path is listed.

Please suggest how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let rsync find the files? Check https://superuser.com/questions/775140/how-can-i-rsync-a-set-of-subdirectories
Or try add quotes in your commad

```
 shpass -p "password" ssh admin@10.98.9.34 'find /results/analysis/output/Home/*/plugin_out/coverageAnalysis_out.*/*.xls -type f -mtime -5 -exec rsync {} /home/balasat/mdl3/Test'
```

If you run `ssh-copy-id admin@10.98.9.34` and hit enter couple of times, you don't need `shpass` anymore. Check https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-passwordless-ssh-login/

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) to automatically rsync files/directories when they are changed.